# FragmentTransaction is changing the order upon replace() called

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a main LinearLayout with two children. One of these is a fragment and the other one is a Linearlayout which has its own children. When I call `fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.mainLayout, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();` the 2 children change position. The fragment that was at the top is now at the bottom. How can I fix this?

My xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<fragment
    android:name="mojavozacka.testovi_za_vozacka_dozvola.Znaci2Fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:layout_weight="1"></fragment>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayoutAppbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/s202_background" />
</LinearLayout>
```

EDIT:
some Java code added

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager;
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle b)
{
    super.onCreate(b);
    setContentView(R.layout.test_layout);

    fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
...
```

some method called when a View from the Fragment is clicked and the Fragment view is being changed.

```
Znaci4Fragment fragment;
private void prasanje1()
{
    fragment = new Znaci4Fragment();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.mainLayout, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

Comment: Can you give us the relevant source code?

Comment: sure, here is my java code take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this,

```
<fragment
    android:name="mojavozacka.testovi_za_vozacka_dozvola.Znaci2Fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:layout_weight="1"></fragment>
```

add a container,

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"/>
```

then replace the container with fragment,

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```